# Android Studio Deployment of "External" Files

Tags: android, android-studio, deployment

I want to deploy files (no mater what kind: .jpg, .db, .txt, etc.), that exists in the development machine, into the target machine.

Embarcadero RadStudio, for example, has a deployment mechanism (Project -> Deployment) that doesn't need any coding. You just define the local path (ex: c:\myprogram\something.txt) and the destination (ex: .\assets\internal).

How I do the same with Android Studio?

Comment: There is no such mechanism in AS, Just copy paste the file from dev machine to assets folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is really the same thing or a workaround, but worked for me:

1) Create a assets folder: app\src\main\assets

2) Copy file you need to the folder (this files are automatically copied to device)

3) Access files using the relative path...

3-b) Copy file to desired location, as someone else example for databases:

```
    //Open a stream for reading, located in the assets
    InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    //Create a stream for writing the database byte by byte
    OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH);

    //Copy the database
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
        localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    //FLUSH THE OUT STREAM
    localDbStream.flush();

    //Close the streams
    localDbStream.close();
    externalDbStream.close();
```